# Adapt to or adapt in

Tags: prepositions

> Team worker able to **adapt to/in** highly dynamic and changing situations

Which form is more suitable: "adapt to" or "adapt in"?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

*Adapt to X* means you change yourself in order to deal with X.  Usually implies you've made 1 change in reaction to 1 X.

*Adapt in X* means X is the situation where you are changing yourself, which is more vague and implies you are doing anything possible or multiple things to adapt.

> We're adapting to a high crime rate = We've planning or have done something specific in reaction to the high crime rate.
>
> We're adapting in a high crime rate = As the high crime rate produces specific consequences, we will do things in reaction to what we experience as it comes up.  No planning.  We're "doing it live."

Answer (score 0):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adapt

I don't think "adapt in" is proper.  In this context, the worker either can or cannot "adapt to" the environment.